# Por que este if se muestra SI NO se cumple la condición

Tags: php

Tengo este problema de nuevo, se muestra un if, pero no se cumple la condición:

```html
<?php
    if ($quediaes=="Tue" || 10 <= $hora && $hora <= 11 ) {
         echo'<a href="../canal-1.php" class="waves-effect waves-light btn"> <font color="#FFFFFF">VER</font></a>';
    }elseif ($quediaes=="Tue" || 12 <= $hora && $hora <= 13 ) {
         echo'<a href="" class="waves-effect waves-light btn"> <font color="#FFFFFF">VER</font></a>';
    }
?>
```

En teoria, si es cierta hora, el  tiene un enlace, y a otra hora ese `<a>` no tiene link

Ahora me lleva a `canal-1.php` pero no se cumple esa condición.

**EDITO**

Gracias a `alanfcm` por la respuesta, pero me surgió algo de nuevo:
Ahora se muestran los dos enlaces a la vez, como si las dos condiciones se cumplieran, cosa que no pasa, cada una se tendría que mostrar a cierta hora, pero se muestran a la vez:

```html
<?php
if ($quediaes=="Tue" || (0 <= $hora && $hora <= 18) ) {
            echo'<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn"> <font color="#FFFFFF">VER</font></a>';
          }

if ($quediaes=="Tue" || (19 <= $hora && $hora <= 22) ) {
            echo'<a href="/superliga/canal-1.php" class="waves-effect waves-light btn"> <font color="#FFFFFF">VER</font></a>';
                                    }    
?>
```

Comment: Debes usar AND (&&) en vez de OR ( | | ) ... ya que tu código así como está: si $quediaes tiene el valor "Tue" tu condición se evaluará como verdadera...

Comment: quieres que se muestre el link: 1) sólo los días martes a cierta hora 2) los días martes, o a las horas indicadas (cualquier día) ?? .. te respondí asumiendo la opción 1 (me adelante xD, mal hecho)

Comment: Si, gracias, lo vi tarde, eso, me confundí, entonces el `||` decia "si es martes `o` son las 10" por ejemplo no?

Comment: claro, martes o las 10 (de cualquier día), con el || si se cumple cualquiera de las condiciones se evaluará como verdadero... por eso te consultaba que es lo que tú necesitabas..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu condicion esta mal.  Si entiendo bien, tu proposito es que la hora este entre  10  y 11, entonces necesitas parentesis.  Seria asi:

```
<?php
    if ($quediaes=="Tue" || (10 <= $hora && $hora <= 11) ) {
         echo'<a href="../canal-1.php" class="waves-effect waves-light btn"> <font color="#FFFFFF">VER</font></a>';
    }elseif ($quediaes=="Tue" || (12 <= $hora && $hora <= 13) ) {
         echo'<a href="" class="waves-effect waves-light btn"> <font color="#FFFFFF">VER</font></a>';
   }    
?>
```

Comment: Si, ahora si, pero por que los parentesis?

Comment: Quieres que se cumpla si `$quediaes` es True o si la hora esta dentro del rango.  Para que este dentro del rango, las dos condiciones de la hora deben de ser verdaderas.

Comment: Edité la pregunta, hay algo que me pasa con las condiciones.

Comment: Es porque cambiaste el `elseif` por `if`

Comment: Pero con el `elseif` no me abre el link

Comment: El `elseif` no tiene nada que ver con el link.  Si no te abre debe haber otro problema.

Comment: Cual puede ser, creo otro tema?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83046/discussion-between-alanfcm-and-matiphp).

Comment: Podes creer, **NO ME ANDA**, otra vez, lo tengo asi, cambié el "Tue" por "Wed" y solo me aparece el primer if

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar AND (`&&`) en vez de OR (`||`) ya que tu código así como está: si `$quediaes` tiene el valor "Tue" se evaluará como verdadera y las condiciones de hora serán ignoradas

El código sería:

```php
if ($quediaes=="Tue" && (0 <= $hora && $hora <= 18) ) {
    echo'<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn"> <font color="#FFFFFF">VER</font></a>';
} elseif ($quediaes=="Tue" && (19 <= $hora && $hora <= 22) ) {
    echo'<a href="/superliga/canal-1.php" class="waves-effect waves-light btn"> <font color="#FFFFFF">VER</font></a>';
}
```

Comment: Podes creer, **NO ME ANDA**, otra vez, lo tengo asi, cambié el "Tue" por "Wed" y solo me aparece el primer if

Comment: ahora verifica la hora

Comment: verifica que las condiciones de hora se cumplan..

Comment: Si, acá son las 19, y se tendría que mostrar el put* elseif, pero no

Comment: más raro que pescado con hombros.. haz un echo de las variables $quediaes y $hora para ver q valores tienen..

Comment: Si, $quediaes muestra "Wed", eso esta bien, pero $hora, no me muestra nada, estas son mis variables de $}hora

Comment: Lo dejé así: `if ($quediaes=="Wed" && (19 <= $quehoraes && $quehoraes <= 22)) {
    echo'<a href="/superliga/canal-1.php" class="waves-effect waves-light btn"> <font color="#FFFFFF">VER</font></a>';
}`   - VARIABLES: `$quediaes=date("D");
$quehoraes=date("G");`

Comment: debes asegurarte que en php tu variable que almacena la hora esté mostrando el valor correcto.. que valor te muestra cuando haces echo date('G'); ... el valor impreso coincide con la hora???